# Move anchor text in fancy header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, books

In the code below, if the Chapter number is 2 characters or more, it clashes with the chapter name.  How to go about moving JUST the chapter number closer to the edge of the document as shown in the graphic here:[image]

Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,letterpaper,draft]{book}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}

%======================================================================================
%   CHAPTER THUMB
%======================================================================================

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\pagestyle{plain}

%======================================================================================
%   PAGE HEADERS
%======================================================================================

\def\subsectiontitle{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\def\subsectiontitle{#1}}

\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration
\usepackage{csquotes}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}
\newif\ifchapterwidthstar
\newcommand\printchapternumber{\ifchapterwidthstar\else\thechapter\fi}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@chapter{\@afterheading}{\chapterwidthstarfalse\@afterheading}{}{}
\patchcmd\@schapter{\@afterheading}{\chapterwidthstartrue\@afterheading}{}{}
\makeatother

\hrule width\headwidth height\headrulewidth depth\headrulewidth

\definecolor{line}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{fillh}{RGB}{225,233,251}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}
\newcommand\ftheight{.5in}

\newsavebox\headimageodd
\newsavebox\headimageeven

\NewDocumentCommand{\headimages}{m O{} m O{}}{%
  % #1 - mandotory argument: first image
  % #2 - optional argument for first image
  % #3 - mandotory argument: second image
  % #4 - optional argument for second image
  \savebox{\headimageeven}{%
    \includegraphics[#2]{#1}%
  }%
  \savebox{\headimageodd}{%
    \includegraphics[#4]{#3}%
  }%
}

\headimages{example-image-a}[scale=0.30]{example-image-b}[scale=0.15]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge#1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{10pt}{30pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {}{}{0pt}{\normalfont\fontsize{30}{30}\bfseries#1}[\leavevmode\thispagestyle{fancy}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{10pt}{15pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\Large#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \sffamily\subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages

\fancyhead[O]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[blue!20] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=12cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.42cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries]  at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\textbf{\MakeUppercase{This is very very very long chapter heading}}};
    \else
    \node[anchor=south west, text width=1.8cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\textbf{\printchapternumber}};
    \node[anchor=south west, text width=12cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.4cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\textbf{\MakeUppercase{This is very very ver long chapter heading}}};
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north east, minimum size=1in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\usebox\headimageodd};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\fancyhead[E]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[blue!20] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[align=right, anchor=south east, text width=12cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.4cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\Huge\textbf{\rightmark}};
    \node[anchor=north west, minimum size=1in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\usebox\headimageeven};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \part{Text Part 1}
  Text to be included as a paragraph below custom part. The text should be on the same page just under the heading.
  \renewcommand\thechapter{P1}
  \chapter{Problem 1}
  Here is my text for Problem 1.
  \chapter{Solution 1}
  Here is my text for Solution 1.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not result in the image you posted (other font size).

Comment: What is the problem? Just can change the x position of the corresponding tikz node.

Comment: The \fancyhead[LO] entry doesn't appear to do anything, or at least is being overwritten by the [O] entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decrease the `xshift` of the `oddpagenum` node and at the same time increase its `text width` by the same amount (`.4\hdheight`) to keep the chapter title in the same place.

[image: a]

```
\node[anchor=south west, text width=1.8cm + .4\hdheight, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.1\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\textbf{\printchapternumber}};
```